# MySQL trigger will not execute but the code functions correctly

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a trigger that will not execute automatically, but the code functions perfectly if I run if manually. The purpose of this trigger is to populate a custom WordPress table from two other tables. (Note. This same query and trigger work in a different WordPress database with the same processes.) This query essentially flattens the WordPress data into a single row so that users can pull simple reports.

This trigger is
Name: insert_guess_after_form
Table: wpi3rfQWE_cd7_data
Time: AFTER
Event: INSERT

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_guess_after_form2
    AFTER INSERT
    ON cf7_vdata FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO wpi3rfQWE_guesses (guess_id, guess_user_id, guess_date, guess_name, guess_email, guess_advocate, guess_text, gpos1, gpos2, gpos3, gpos4, gpos5, gpos6, gpos7)
SELECT distinct eG.data_id, eG.cf7_id, CURRENT_DATE, eName.value , eMail.value,  eAdv.value, eG.Value, SUBSTRING(eG.value, 1, 1), SUBSTRING(eG.value, 2, 1), SUBSTRING(eG.value, 3, 1), SUBSTRING(eG.value, 4, 1), SUBSTRING(eG.value, 5, 1), SUBSTRING(eG.value, 6, 1), SUBSTRING(eG.value, 7, 1)
FROM wpi3rfQWE_cf7_vdata_entry eG 
LEFT JOIN wpi3rfQWE_cf7_vdata_entry eAdv ON eG.data_id = eAdv.data_id  
LEFT JOIN wpi3rfQWE_cf7_vdata_entry eName ON eG.data_id = eName.data_id
LEFT JOIN wpi3rfQWE_cf7_vdata_entry eMail ON eG.data_id = eMail.data_id
JOIN wpi3rfQWE_cf7_vdata v ON v.id = eG.data_id 
WHERE 1
-- AND (eG.value REGEXP '^T[A-Z]{6}$' OR eG.value REGEXP '^[A-Z]U[A-Z]{5}$')
AND eG.name = 'your-subject'
AND eAdv.name  = 'your-advocate'
AND eMail.name = 'your-email'
AND eG.data_id > (SELECT max(guess_id) FROM wpi3rfQWE_guesses)
GROUP BY eG.data_id
END
```

One thing that I noticed is that the Definer is cpses_alcmz5yovh@localhost.
The former trigger on a different database used root@localhost. Will that be the problem? And how would I fix that?

Comment: Please add the create table...for each row part of the trigger and confirm the trigger as been created

Comment: *Will that be the problem?* Of course. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html *CREATE TRIGGER requires the TRIGGER privilege for the table associated with the trigger. If the DEFINER clause is present, the privileges required depend on the user value, as discussed in Section 25.6, “Stored Object Access Control”. If binary logging is enabled, CREATE TRIGGER might require the SUPER privilege, as discussed in Section 25.7, “Stored Program Binary Logging”.*

Comment: I use PHP Admin to create the original trigger. But following your suggestion, I dropped the trigger and attempted to add the new trigger like the code below, but got error

Comment: changed code above

Comment: In this case, it appears that the problem is caused by phpMyAdmin applying the CPanel user. Instead, I will need to log into the mysql database as the WordPress user, or as root. In my hosted environment, I'm not sure how to do that, but that's the next step.